# Preventing collisions between permalinks and subdirectories

Tags: plugins, permalinks, directory

I've deployed a WordPress installation on the root of my site. This site also has a few subdirectories that should remain accessible, such as `/somefolder/`. I've configured WordPress to use `/%postname%/` as its permalink structure. While importing existing blog posts from another WordPress install, I noticed that a certain post used `somefolder` as its slug, which creates a collision.

I know that I can just change the slug, but I was wondering if WordPress offers a mechanism to check for permalink/subdirectory collisions.

Comment: @toscho I don't think this question is a duplicate. This question is about collisions with files in the filesystem not within wordpress.

Comment: @s1lv3r Isn’t that the same principle? Instead of `$slug == 'portfolio'` you use `is_dir( ABSPATH . "/$slug" )`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I got it now. Transferleistung. :-P